# How to design this table better?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a table called `interests` of school subjects for each student.

A student **must** have at least 3 subject interests, up to a maximum of 7.

The possible subject interests are:

- science
- math
- english
- history
- art
- physical education
- foreign language

However in both my table designs, I can't figure out how to normalize the table.

---

First Table: `interests` (8 columns)

```
student_id(pk) | interest_1 | interest_2 | ... | interest_7
```

In this design `interests_1` to `interest_7` are the columns. If a student chooses science, math, and english as his interest, then

- `interest_1` is set to `science`
- `interest_2` is set to `math`
- `interest_3` is set to `english`
- `interest_4` to `interest_7` are set to `null`

---

Second Table: `interests` (8 columns)

```
student_id(pk) | science | math | english | ... | foreign_lanaguage
```

In this design, the school subjects are now the columns. If a student's interests are science, math, and english then those columns are set to `true` and the remaining columns are set to `false`.

- `science` is set to `true`
- `math` is set to `true`
- `english` is set to `true`
- `history` is set to `false`
- `art` is set to `false`
- `physical_education` is set to `false`
- `foreign_language` is set to `false`

---

How else can I design this table(s)?

And, how would I select only the subjects that a particular student is interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how scalable you want to be.  On one hand your design works.

On the other hand if you want to add new classes you would have to go in and modify the table.

Another approach would be to have 3 tables:

**Student**  ID, name

**Class**  ID, name

**StudentInterrests**  ID, StudentID, ClassID

if the student class combination does not appear in the studentinterrests table they are not interrested in the course

Your select of student interests would look something like this:

```
SELECT StudentName, CourseName
FROM Student
LEFT JOIN StudentInterrests ON Student.ID = StudentInterrests.StudentID
LEFT JOIN Class ON StudentInterrests.ClassID = Class.ID
```

Your result from this would be:
*John, Math

John, English

John, SocialStudies*

**For your min and max requirements:** I would recommend putting the requirements at the application level since it seems more application logic than a constraint on the database.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal The constraint "between 3 and 7" can't reasonably be expressed at the relational schema level; and it's definitely not a good enough reason to break normalisation in your schema. (Even if it's easier to implement with a `CHECK` with your original proposal, in the normalised version it'd probably require deferred constraint checking to not break in the middle of a transaction before you add interests 2 and 3.)

Comment: I agree with @millimoose and was just updating my answer as you posted your comments.

Comment: @millimoose - I know, I just wanted him to point to this point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When normalising it's important to recognise the correct primary key for each table that you are creating. Break the fields into their most basic form. What do you have? You have student_id and interests. Since the interests can be either true or false, you can just store the name of the interest in the same column as other interests, so if they don't exist against a student_id, then that student is not interested in them.

This is bordering a homework question, so it seems silly to solve this for you. Instead I'll put you on the right track. The student_id is not the primary key you are looking for, but it is an index. You are looking to get a 3 column table for the most ideal data structure.

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting this kind of relation: make 7 tables, one for each interest with a column for student_id. When a student chooses a subject interest, their student_id will be inserted into the corresponding interest.

Comment: No, why would you have one column for each interest? You can just enter 'science' into a general 'interest' column. You only need one table.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to meet your requirements your design will work. I see two other easily implemented options that can meet the given spec.

1.) Students table with the 7 interests foreign keyed to the interest table; use a set of unique constraints to ensure that no student has two of the same interest. Use a nullable foreign key and allow nulls on items 4-7.

2.) Break the interests table out. The rule works 99% the same, though the mandatory interests would only trigger the constraint once interests are selected (so the student can have 0 OR 3-8 interests). This is a slightly more reasonable approach so you can populate the student table separately from interests. This keeps things extensible.

Both approaches are in the third normal form, doable with ANSI-92 compliant databases. Example implementation of #2 in SQL server is below.

[image: Table layout]

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Interests]    Script Date: 11/9/2012 8:32:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Interests](
    [interestID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [interestText] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [interestDescription] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Interests] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [interestID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[StudentInterests]    Script Date: 11/9/2012 8:32:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests](
    [studentInterestID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [studentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [interestID_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [interestID_2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [interestID_3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [interestID_4] [int] NULL,
    [interestID_5] [int] NULL,
    [interestID_6] [int] NULL,
    [interestID_7] [int] NULL,
    [interestID_8] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentInterests] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_2] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_2] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_3] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_3] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_4] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_4] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_4] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_5] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_5] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_6] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_6] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_7] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_7] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_8] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentInterestID] ASC,
    [interestID_8] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_StudentInterests_9] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [studentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Students]    Script Date: 11/9/2012 8:32:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [studentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [lastName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [studentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests1] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_2])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests2] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_3])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests2]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests3] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_4])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests3]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests4] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_5])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests4]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests5] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_6])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests5]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests6] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_7])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests6]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests7] FOREIGN KEY([interestID_8])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Interests] ([interestID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Interests7]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Students] FOREIGN KEY([studentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Students] ([studentID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StudentInterests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentInterests_Students]
GO
```